# me salta un error al apretar un boton

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo un problema q al apretar un boton me salta el error

```
self.cont2.destroy()
AttributeError: 'Ventana' object has no attribute 'cont2'
```

no se en q le estoy errando, subo una parte del código para mostrar lo q pasa al apretar un botón, lo q intento hacer al apretar un botón es abrir un contenedor y destruir otro, no se si se entiende, sino subiré el código completo.

espero se entienda y muchas gracias.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Ventana(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.master.title('Codificador')
        self.master.geometry('500x250')
        self.master.configure(bg='#A2D9CE')
        self.contenedor1()
        
    def contenedor1(self):
        
        self.cont1=tk.Frame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE')
        self.cont1.place(x=0, y=0,width=110, height=220)
        self.label=tk.Label(self.cont1, text='Menu', bg='#A2D9CE').place(x=2, y=10, width=100, height=30)
        self.boton1=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='Iniciar sesión', bg='#34495E', 
                                fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10, command = self.contenedor2).place(x=10, y=35)
        self.boton2=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='registrarse',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10,
                                command=self.contenedor3).place(x=10, y=95)
        self.boton3=tk.Button(self.cont1, text='Salir',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', height=3, width=10).place(x=10, y=155)

    def contenedor2(self):
        self.cont2=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Login')
        self.cont2.place(x=120, y=15, height=220)
        tk.Label(self.cont2, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Usuario').place(x=5, y=12)
        tk.Label(self.cont2, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Contraseña').place(x=5, y=45)
        self.entrada1=tk.Entry(self.cont2).pack(pady=10, padx=80)
        self.entrada2=tk.Entry(self.cont2).pack(pady=8, padx=80)
        self.boton4=tk.Button(self.cont2, text='aceptar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9')                       
        self.boton4.place(x=40, y=120, width=75, height=30)
        self.boton5=tk.Button(self.cont2, text='cancelar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9', command=self.cont2.destroy)
        self.boton5.place(x=170, y=120, width=75, height=30)
        self.cont3.destroy()

    def contenedor3(self):
        self.cont3=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Ingrese los datos')
        self.cont3.place(x=120, y=15, height=220)
        self.lbl1=tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Nombre')
        self.lbl1.place(x=5, y=5)
        self.lbl2=tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Usuario')
        self.lbl2.place(x=5, y=35)
        self.lbl3=tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Contraseña')
        self.lbl3.place(x=5, y=65)
        self.lbl4=tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Correo')
        self.lbl4.place(x=5, y=95)
        self.lbl5=tk.Label(self.cont3, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Key')
        self.lbl5.place(x=5, y=125)
        self.entrada3=tk.Entry(self.cont3)
        self.entrada3.pack(pady=5, padx=80)
        self.entrada4=tk.Entry(self.cont3)
        self.entrada4.pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada5=tk.Entry(self.cont3)
        self.entrada5.pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada6=tk.Entry(self.cont3)
        self.entrada6.pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.entrada7=tk.Entry(self.cont3)
        self.entrada7.pack(pady=6, padx=80)
        self.boton6=tk.Button(self.cont3, text='Aceptar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9')
        self.boton6.place(x=35, y=165, width=80, height=25)
        self.boton7=tk.Button(self.cont3, text='Cancelar',bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9',command=self.cont3.destroy)
        self.boton7.place(x=155, y=165, width=80, height=25)
        self.cont2.destroy()
    
    def contenedor4(self):
        self.cont4=tk.LabelFrame(self.master, bg='#A2D9CE', text='Escriba el texto')
        self.cont4.place(x=120, y=15,width=350, height=220)
        self.entrada8=tk.Listbox(self.cont4, width=35, height=11)
        self.entrada8.place(x=5, y=5)
        self.boton10=tk.Button(self.cont4, text='Codificar', bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9')
        self.boton10.place(x=250, y=25, width=65, height=25)
        self.boton11=tk.Button(self.cont4, text='Aceptar', bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9')
        self.boton11.place(x=250, y=60, width=65, height=25)
        self.boton12=tk.Button(self.cont4, text='Cancelar', bg='#34495E', fg='#E5E7E9')
        self.boton12.place(x=250, y=95, width=65, height=25)


if __name__=='__main__':
    
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=Ventana(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: SI no se ha ejecutado antes la rutina de contenedor2, self.cont2 no existe.

Comment: gracias, ya descubrí como solucionarlo, entendía cual era el error pero no sabia como arreglarlo